# simple example, but I don't understand why there are no leaks

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management

```
- (IBAction) btnFire:(id)sender {

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],   @"/gunShot.wav"];

    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];

    AVPlayer *shotSound = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:filePath];

    [shotSound play];
}
```

If I release shotSound here, it will not not play. At the same time there are no leaks.

Why does Instruments indicate no leaks?  How to release shotSound?

Answer (score 2):

As you will need sound again and again when button is pressed so rather than initiliazing it in button each time you should declare it at class level and either you can initialize it in viewDidLoad method, or you can do this also

```
- (IBAction) btnFire:(id)sender {

 if(shotSound==nil)
{
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],   @"/gunShot.wav"];

        NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];

       shotSound = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:filePath];
}

        [shotSound play];

}
```

release it in `dealloc`. If you just wish to have sound on this action than you can use `AVAudioPlayer`.

Sometimes instrument's leak is not able to detect it, in those cases you can use build and analyse tool. Also, as you said if you release player object then app crashes may be cause it audio is still playing and you release the player(not sure).

Comment: This is the correct answer. `shotSound` should be allocated once and then released in `dealloc` and `viewDidUnload`. I added `viewDidUnload` because there no reason to keep the allocation when the view isn't present. @Ravin's code will initialize it again when it's needed.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean shotSound should be ivar?

Comment: if (ivar--> instance variable) then yes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`AVPlayer *shotSound = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:filePath];`

Note: This returns a new player to play a single audiovisual resource referenced by a given URL.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage in this way?

Comment: If you just want to play a single file I think this would be enough. When you do this the player gets released when the AutoReleasePool is drained